# Continuity and differentiability for a particular function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f$ be the function defined on the real line by

$f(x) =$
\begin{cases}
2x^2,  & \text{if $x \in  \mathbb{Q}$} \\
-3x^2, & \text{if $x \notin  \mathbb{Q}$}  \\
\end{cases}

Then which for the following is true?

A.  $f$ is not continuous and not differentiable everywhere

B.  $f$ is continuous only at $x=0$ and not differentiable everywhere

C.  $f$ is continuous and differentiable only at $x=0$

D.  $f$ is continuous and not differentiable everywhere

E.  $f$ is continuously differentiable everywhere

Answer (score 1):

Use the sequence of characterisation of continuity, together with the familiar property of reals: to every real number, there are two sequences, one of rationals and other of irrationals converging to it (in $\mathbf{R}$).

The differentiability can be investigated based on similar ideas.

> BTW, the answer is (C)

Answer (score 1):

I think a picture helps: ${}{}{}$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answer c is correct. For derivability at 0 take the definition. Recall that a derivable function at a point is also continuous.