# Continuity and Differentiability of some functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

On one of my textbooks has the following exercise:

> Let $f$, $g$ and $h$ be the next functions:
>
> $$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 1& x \in \mathbb{Q}\\ 0 & x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\end{array}\right.\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;g(x)=xf(x)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;h(x)=xg(x)$$
>
> Prove that $g$ is continuous only on $x=0$ and $h$ is differentiable also only on $x=0$.

I know something about $f$: is a Dirichlet function and is **not** continuous (**nor** differentiable) everywhere.

I remember this matter from college and I think we proved this by showing that, for every $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$, the limit $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ is not well defined so we can't say that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$ and, by this, we conclude that $f$ is **not** continuous on $x_0$.

Since is **not** continuous on $x_0$, $f$ is **not** differentiable on $x_0$ as well.

Here's my question: Doesn't the same argument show that $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$ is **not** well defined? Or that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{h(x)-h(0)}{x}$ is also **not** well defined? How can I state that  $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=0$? Or $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{h(x)-h(0)}{x}=0$?

A similar question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523973/continuity-and-differentiability-for-a-particular-function), however the answers don't provide any formal proof of this particular exercise (nor a leading clue to get it as far as I understand).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the sandwich theorem and use $|f|\leq 1$, i.e.
$$0\leq|g(x)|=|x||f(x)|\leq |x|\rightarrow 0 \mbox{ for }x\rightarrow 0.$$
Can you now do the same for the differential quotient of $h$?

Comment: Yes, I can. I'm picture it now... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing about $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ which is not well-defined. What happens is that that limit doesn't exist, whatever the number $x_0$ is.

The same thing occurs with the function $g$ *except* if $x_0=0$. Then we have$$(\forall x\in\mathbb R):\bigl\lvert g(x)\bigr\rvert\leqslant\lvert x\rvert$$and therefore $\lim_{x\to0}g(x)=0=g(0)$.

A similar thing occurs with $h$.

Comment: Actually, I meant that the limit doesn't exist (I shouldn't have say not well defined). Thanks for your answer, but I prefer to use the squeeze theorem as mentioned by @humanStampedist. But I understood yours as well.